# SfdcSqlException: ORA-00972: identifier is too long

Tags: soql, limits

I'm wokring on building custom hierarchy for accounts. I used [this lib](https://github.com/ChuckJonas/hierarchical-search) to build queries to get descendants.

I have a field named `AlternatParent__c` (changed name, same length though). This is the field that builds the hierarchy. But when I run descendants search I get the following error.

`System.UnexpectedException: common.exception.SfdcSqlException: ORA-00972: identifier is too long`

The error only appears in Sandbox. In scratch org it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

As it is stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59198505/tableau-error-ora-00972-identifier-is-too-long):

`An ORA-00972 means you are using a database column or object identifier name that is too long`

In my case the problem was that the query that I try to execute has the following relation field:

`AlternatParent__r.AlternatParent__r.AlternatParent__r.AlternatParent__r.AlternatParent__r.AlternatParent__c`

So I changed the depth level of my query to one less:

`AlternatParent__r.AlternatParent__r.AlternatParent__r.AlternatParent__r.AlternatParent__c`

And it worked perfectly. Beware of long queries and may the Force.com be with you!